# Oscillatory integral independent of a parameter

Tags: cv.complex-variables, harmonic-analysis, integration

Let $h: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{C}$ be a positive definite function, continuous at the origin. (In fact, $h$ is the Fourier transform of a finite measure). Define the oscillatory integral 
$$Q(t) := \int_0^\infty \frac{\text{Im} \{ h(u)^t\}}{u} du, \quad t > 0.$$ 
Are there  non-trivial examples of $h$ that makes $Q$ independent of $t$?

Is there a known class of functions $\{ h \}$ that have this property?

Comment: $h(u)=e^{iu}$ qualifies, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes it does. Unfortunately for my purposes, it is a trivial case, i.e it's the Fourier transform of a point mass.